# Flask WTForms Validate on Submit not working

Tags: python, html, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am working on a page in my application where a user submits a review on a review page using WTForms, and upon clicking the submit button, the text "Success" should display. This is currently not happening, as upon clicking submit, the review page simply reloads itself but with an error.
I have created other pages requiring form validation which has worked, except for this one and I can't seem to figure out why, despite replicating the code from other pages.
Any insights are much appreciated!

Screenshot of error image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHUKO.png]

Here is my HTML code

```
<html>
    <body>
        {% for books in books %}
        {{books.title}} 
        {% endfor %}

<form action = "{{ url_for('review', isbn=books.isbn)}}", method = "POST">
    <div>
    <br>{{ form.review(class_='form-control',placeholder ='Leave a review here')}}</br>
    <ul>
    {% for error in form.review.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <br>{{ form.rating(class_='form-control',placeholder ='Leave a rating here')}}</br>
    <ul>
    {% for error in form.rating.errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {{form.csrf_token}}  
    {{form.submit_button }}
  
</div>

</form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Python Code

```
@app.route("/review/<string:isbn>", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required 
def review(isbn):
     review = Books.query.filter_by(isbn=isbn).all()
     review_form = ReviewForm()
     if review_form.validate_on_submit():
           return "Success"
     
     return render_template("review.html", books = review, form = review_form)
```

WTForms fields

```
class ReviewForm(FlaskForm):
     """ Review """
     review = StringField('review_label', widget=TextArea(), validators = [InputRequired(message = "Review can't be empty")])
     rating = StringField('rating_label', validators= [InputRequired(message="Please input a rating")])
     submit_button = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following. Let me know if this helps! :)

```
from markupsafe import escape
@app.route("/review/<string:isbn>", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required 
def review(isbn):
     review = Books.query.filter_by(isbn=isbn).all()
     review_form = ReviewForm()
     if review_form.validate_on_submit():
           return "Success %s" % escape(isbn)
     
     return render_template("review.html", books = review, form = review_form)
```

[reference flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/)

Comment: Thank you for your input! Unfortunately it did not work. I think the problem lies in the <string:isbn> route (though I'm not sure of the root cause myself). I tried two methods which temporarily solved the problem 
1) I removed the route and all instances of 'isbn' from all places in my code that contained it and it worked - the paged showed 'success' when I clicked on the submit button.  2) I redirected the user to a different page  return redirect(url_for('success')). If you or anyone has any insights on the issue, do let me know!